# How do I stop refresh useForm?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, react-hook-form

When I click on submit all the field information goes to browser's url, and the values didn't go to backend and the errors messages from yup didn't work too.

I try use the event.preventDefault in handleSubmit to stop the refresh in useForm but still the same.

```
import React from 'react';
import { useForm, type SubmitHandler } from 'react-hook-form';
import { type IFormData } from 'interfaces/ISession';
import { yupResolver } from '@hookform/resolvers/yup';
import * as yup from 'yup';
import { useAppDispatch } from 'redux/hooks';
import { saveEmail } from 'redux/reducers/usersSlice';
import { useSessionMutation } from 'shared/httpService';

const schema = yup
  .object({
    email: yup.string().email().required(),
    password: yup.string().min(8).max(16).required(),
  })
  .required();

const Session = (): JSX.Element => {
  const dispatch = useAppDispatch();
  const [session] = useSessionMutation();

  const {
    register,
    handleSubmit,
    formState: { errors },
  } = useForm<IFormData>({
    resolver: yupResolver(schema),
  });

  const onSubmit: SubmitHandler<IFormData> = async ({ email, password }, event) => {
    if (event !== undefined) {
      event.preventDefault();
    }
    try {
      await session({ email, password }).unwrap();
      dispatch(saveEmail(email));
    } catch (error) {
      console.error(error);
    }
  };

  return (
    <form onSubmit={() => handleSubmit(onSubmit)}>
      <input type="email" defaultValue="" {...register('email')} placeholder="email" />
      <span>{errors.email?.message}</span>

      <input type="password" defaultValue="" {...register('password')} placeholder="senha" />
      <span>{errors.password?.message}</span>

      <input type="submit" />
    </form>
  );
};

export default Session;
```

I tryed use event.preventDefault but still the same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pass the return value of `handleSubmit` itself to `onSubmit` so that it actually gets access to the `event` parameter. (There is no need to manually call `event.preventDefault()`.)

```
<form onSubmit={handleSubmit(onSubmit)}>
```

Comment: I changed it and now everything are working. Thanks!!

Comment: I put that anonymous function just because the eslint show the error @typescript-eslint/no-misused-promises, so I changed these error to warn.